# problem with flask-restful circular nested resources

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have two fields in separate files to marshal with. They are:

```
from games.controllers.api.categories import category_fields
game_fields = {
    'title': fields.String,
    'developer': fields.String,
    'categories': fields.List(fields.Nested(category_fields)),
    'uri': fields.Url('game')
}
```

and

```
from games.controllers.api.games import game_fields
category_fields = {
    'name': fields.String,
    'games': fields.List(fields.Nested(game_fields)),
    'uri': fields.Url('category')
}
```

When I run the app it throws me an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'category_fields' from 'games.controllers.api.categories'
```

Obviously the problem is with circular imports. So how should I solve this?

**Btw**: the 'developer' part in game_fields shows me "`<Developer 1>`". And when I change it to "developer_id": fields.Integer, it gives me developer id with no problem. But I want it to be like "developer": "EA Sports". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A recursive structure like this is bound to give you problems, but if you are decided on it, this is one possible way to avoid circular import errors:

```py
game_fields = {
    'title': fields.String,
    'developer': fields.String,
    'uri': fields.Url('game')
}
from games.controllers.api.categories import category_fields
game_fields['categories'] = fields.List(fields.Nested(category_fields))
```

```py
category_fields = {
    'name': fields.String,
    'uri': fields.Url('category')
}
from games.controllers.api.games import game_fields
category_fields['games'] = fields.List(fields.Nested(game_fields))
```

As far as your second question, you haven't described what your `Developer` class looks like. If you have control over this class, you can change how this class renders itself as a string and make it be the name of the developer instead of `<Developer id>`.

Comment: this solved my first problem. but about second, are you suggesting me to create something like developer_fields to marshal with?

Comment: actually it gave me the error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. but anyways, i got your point..

Comment: If you want to render `Developer` objects as strings, all you need to do is add the proper string representation in the class. You seem to have this defined as `<Developer :id>`. If you change it to be the developer name you'll get what you want.